# Group Row values as Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset, which records temperatures of devices:

```
Device_ID Temperature Label
1           50          0
1           40          0
2           34          0
1           78          0
2           66          1
3           88          0
1           12          0
2           33          0
3           91          0
```

Devices can send temperature at any time. The above dataset is already sorted by time.

What I want to do?

> Classify devices based on their temperature pattern.

I already have the labels for the dataset, labels indicate whether the devices went bad after a measurement (1 means that after this measurement the device went bad, 0 means its okay). Once the label goes "bad", the device is now permanently bad and I need not consider the following measurements for that id.

So, I want to construct the classification dataset as:

```
Device_ID  T1  T2 T3 T4 ... Tn Label

1          50 40 78 ...          0
2          34 66 .....           1 (33 measurement now does not matter)
```

So, my question is **how do I convert these time series values in the rows to columns in Pandas?** How to do this task **efficiently**?

I can use Pivot, but Pivot works only for Categorical variables.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

Create a new helper column `col` using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and a helper series `label` of max Label for each 'Device_ID'. Then use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) your helper series:

```
df['col'] = 'T' + (df.groupby('Device_ID').Temperature.cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
labels = df.groupby('Device_ID')['Label'].max()

df_new = df.pivot(index='Device_ID', columns='col', values='Temperature').assign(Label=labels)
print(df_new)

col          T1    T2    T3    T4  Label
Device_ID                               
1          50.0  40.0  78.0  12.0      0
2          34.0  66.0  33.0   NaN      1
3          88.0  91.0   NaN   NaN      0
```

Comment: thanks a lot. how could i not select the time series values that appear after the max label has been selected? i.e. 33 should not be present in the time series of device id = 2.